# Setup SSH for Auto Login without a Password

Tags: ssh, sshd

Well, I have 2 computers call 120 and 110. I am trying to configure a ssh connection without password from 110 to 120. This is what i have done in the 120:

```
1- ssh-keygen -t rsa
2- scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@110:.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and then in the 110:

```
1- chmod 700 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This steps don't work because it keeps asking for the password. So, I tried to do the opposite, from 120 to 110 and doing exactly the same thing it works.
I also change the `PermitRootLogin yes` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file of both computers.

I am out of ideas. Any suggestion?

EDIT:

This is what I got using ssh -vv:

```
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.168.1.120's password:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this (after generating the key):

```
ssh-add
```